# Responsive div and image, where images have different sizes

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble getting the responsiveness to work...

I have several divs where each have the size of 500pxx500px and images inside the divs have different sizes.

I am trying to get them both to be responsive...without any progress.

I have made it work for resolution up to (max-width) 320px.

Here's the jsfiddle so you guys can see.

http://jsfiddle.net/42b15toa/

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div>
        <img src="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7307/16418106076_c4fbbe9ef7_b.jpg" class="size-1" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7307/16418106076_c4fbbe9ef7_b.jpg" class="size-2" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7307/16418106076_c4fbbe9ef7_b.jpg" class="size-3" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7307/16418106076_c4fbbe9ef7_b.jpg" class="size-4" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7307/16418106076_c4fbbe9ef7_b.jpg" class="size-5" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7307/16418106076_c4fbbe9ef7_b.jpg" class="size-6" />
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#container {
    padding: 0 10px;
}

    #container div {
        width: 500px;
        height: 500px;
        background: rgba(81, 81, 81, 0.3);
        float: left;
        margin: 10px;
        text-align: center;
        position: relative;
    }

        #container div img {
            position: absolute;
            margin: auto;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 0;
        }

        #container div span {
            display: none;
        }

.size-1 {
    height: 400px;
    width: 300px;
}

.size-2,
.size-6 {
    height: 300px;
    width: 500px;
}

.size-3 {
    height: 300px;
    width: 400px;
}

.size-4 {
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
}

.size-5 {
    height: 500px;
    width: 300px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
    #tags {
        width: 250px;
    }

    #divProcessing {
        width: 80%;
        font-size: 15px;
    }

    #container div {
        height: 350px;
        width: 280px;
    }

    .size-1,
    .size-2,
    .size-3,
    .size-4,
    .size-5,
    .size-6 {
        height: 350px;
        width: 280px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try:

```
   #container div img {
        position: absolute;
        margin: auto;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        bottom: 0;
    }
```

The trick is the max-width: 100% and width: 100% - and to preserve the images aspect ratio we include the height: auto.  If this does not matter feel free to omit that.

Results: http://jsfiddle.net/ee7ddpoe/

An article that may be helpful:  http://alistapart.com/article/responsive-images-in-practice
Or an older article which uses a different term: fluid-images - http://alistapart.com/article/fluid-images

Comment: But setting max-width and width to 100% would alter the size of the images inside each div and I don't want that...

Comment: I get it now, you are trying to center the images and make sure that they fill only to their own max width?  Try removing width: 100%;  and definitely get rid of the height on the size classes

Comment: Can you please show an example...how would height alter the image if removed?